# Expected initializer before 'token'

Tags: c++

I know there are several questions about this error message but I did not find a suitable solution for my case. I want to export the Filter class from a library. Visual Studio 2013 just compiles fine, but gcc throws the error:

```
prog.cpp:16:17: error: expected initializer before 'Filter'
 class DllExport Filter{
                 ^
prog.cpp:22:6: error: 'Filter' has not been declared
 void Filter::setFilter(const std::vector<float>& vFilter, unsigned int uNumThreads) {
      ^
```

The code:

```
#ifndef _GNULINUX
#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DllExport __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
    namespace FilterAPI {
#endif

class DllExport Filter{
public:
    static void setFilter(const std::vector<float>& vFilter, unsigned int uNumThreads);

};

void Filter::setFilter(const std::vector<float>& vFilter, unsigned int uNumThreads) {
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  //  namespace FilterAPI
}  //  extern "C" {
#endif
```

See also
https://ideone.com/3VV4AH

Edit:

flags in the make file are:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.8

# compile CXX with /usr/bin/c++
CXX_FLAGS = -fPIC  

CXX_DEFINES = -DFilter_Library_EXPORTS
```

Comment: I compile your code without any errors with `g++ -D_GNULINUX -c ideone_3VV4AH.cpp ` how you compile your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem in wrong define,
should be `#ifndef __linux`, you can find out `gcc` defaults
with `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to explicitly declare the visibility to be "default". It matters on Windows, yes, but on Linux/POSIX the default is what you want.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  #define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define DllExport
#endif
```

This is the more common idiom, at least.